# Working in Germany and job offer in Italy

Tags: schengen, blue-card

I am Indian citizen. I am currently working in Germany. I got job offer from a company to work in Italy. They are ready to apply for an entry visa and blue card. Since I am already in Germany and have a valid company-bound German Residence Permit, do I need to go back to India for an entry visa or I can direclty go to Italy for work and do local formalities?

Comment: Can anybody help in ths...